# AWS RDS IP Address and Firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, intranet, rds

I have an issue where we have a large intranet as well as some resources in AWS and one of our internal servers needs to talk to an RDS instance in AWS.

We've ran into problems where our RDS has changed IP addresses, and this causes our intranet firewall rules to no longer be effective.

I've been told our RDS cannot have a static IP address for a variety of reasons, but how should we handle our internal Firewall configuration if the IP address is going to constantly change?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your RDS instance inside of a VPC, and use a bastion host (with a static IP address) to access the VPC.

Or you should use a VPN to make the RDS instance look local to your network and not worry about its changing IP.